# Robots: moving face, or no face

Tags: interaction-design

Form a UX, perspective.

What would be the advantages of a robot with a moving face, versus, those of a robot with no face.

Thanks.

Comment: I fail to see the UX problem that needs solving here. This is bordering on a philosophy discussion question rather than a User Experience problem in need of a solution.

Comment: @JonW I am voting to reopen because although the question is very broad, there has been UX research on giving robots human-like characteristics, and this can be answerable through thoroughness and cited sources.